# Checkbox to (Check & un-check All) in gridview with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, gridview, checkbox

I'm trying to make a simple **(Check & un-check All)** in a grid view with **"AngularJS"** but all examples that I found depends on **ng-repeat**, any help will be appreciated.

The issue is I used **(ng-checked)** to achieve my target but when the master checkbox is checked the child checkboxes doesn't fire **onchange** event
so I couldn't complete my task to make some changes depend on whether the child checkbox is checked or not

```
    var ngGridApp = angular.module('gridApp', []);

   ngGridApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = "gridCtrl";
    $scope.ids = {};

    $scope.ConLog = function (val) {
        console.log(val);
    };

    $scope.CheckUnCheckAll = function () {
        $scope.$watch('ids', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            $scope.ids = newValue;
        });
    }
 }]);
```

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/samehsaeed/q8csfwyz/9/)**

Comment: Please post the code you currently have and explain why you can't or don't want to use `ng-repeat`.

Comment: becuse i'm using ASP.NET and fill a gridview server control from DB, and this GridView rendred as a Table

Comment: Live Example for my code http://jsfiddle.net/samehsaeed/q8csfwyz/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found a solution.
The key is to fill the array first to can work with it later , because I don't use **ng-repeat**, so I need to bind my child check boxes to the **$scope** first

```
var ngGrigApp = angular.module('gridApp', []);

ngGrigApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = "gridCtrl";
    $scope.ids = [];

    $scope.BindIds = (function () {
        angular.element("input[id*=chkBoxSelected]").each(function () {
            $scope.ids.push({ "value": this.value, "IsChecked": this.checked });
        });
    })();

    $scope.triggerAll = function () {

        angular.forEach($scope.ids, function (obj) {
            if ($scope.chkBoxChief) {
                obj.IsChecked = true;
            }
            else {
                obj.IsChecked = false;
            }
        })
    }
}]);
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/samehsaeed/q8csfwyz/12/)**